# MySQL joining multiple column

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have two tables with several columns, and I want to join these tables using an outer join. However, it takes forever. I just think I made a mistake or maybe there are other solutions?

```
create table table_1 (
  sn int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  column1 int(6) NOT NULL,
  column3 int(1) NOT NULL,
  column4 date NOT NULL,
  column5 char(2) NOT NULL,
  column6 int(6) NOT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  column15 int(1) NOT NULL
)

create table table_2 (
sn int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
column1 int(6) NOT NULL,
column3 int(1) NOT NULL,
column4 date NOT NULL,
column5 char(2) NOT NULL,
column6 int(6) NOT NULL,
...
...
column8 int(1) NOT NULL
)
```

I've created an index on these 2 table with column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 and column6.

My problem is I want to right join these two tables with:

```
table_1.column1 = table_2.column1 AND
table_1.column2 = table_2.column2 AND
table_1.column3 = table_2.column3 AND
table_1.column4 = table_2.column4 AND
table_1.column5 = table_2.column5 AND
table_1.column6 = table_2.column6
```

When I execute this query, it takes a very long time. Is there any solution to make this query faster?

Table_1 size: 3 GB and table_2 size: 10 GB. Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at `EXPLAIN <your query>`? If you didn't do it and post result in a textual form in your question along with `SHOW INDEX FROM table_1` and `SHOW INDEX FROM table_2`.

Comment: You want select all columns or check only existence in first table (check null values)? It look like move data from second to first table (depends on sizes and structure).

Comment: The join query was never ends. so I quit after I wait for 1 week, and then I concat the 6 column and use HASH to make a new variable. After that, make index of that HASH, and join them together.